# How can I self-learn Electrical Engineering?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I know it is an awkward question but I love maths, physics, and engineering! Due to my health problems (I am suffering from Psoriasis) I was not able to opt PCM (Physics, Chemistry, and Mathematics) as a stream. But I love it so much that I just started learning Maths from the internet and Physics. It would be amazing if anyone can suggest me how can I self-learn the entire Electrical Engineering curriculum by self.

Please suggest me some resources and what do I need to focus upon. Also, what are the things that I already need to know? A detailed answer would be amazing. Please help me out with this. I also have other several interests but I would like to tackle this one first.

Update: Now this would be kinda funny: I am just 18 years old. But already know Single Variable and Multivariable Calculus. I also know like 2-3 Programming languages (that is what inspired me for electronics). But the worst thing is that I took Commerce in class-11th as a stream. Now no schools and colleges will offer me any course in engineering. But I don't think that will ever stop anyone from learning. So the things that I already know about it MIT OCW, EdX, Coursera, UCIrvine OCW and am persuing things from these online MOOCs but books and things through which I will be able to achieve what I want would be great!

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! Sorry to hear about your health problem and the fact that it is interfering with your goals in education and life. Struggling with health challenges is no fun. I think it would help if you could edit your question to give us a little more information about your age, educational background, resources, and situation. Maybe this would be a more appropriate question for electronics.SE: -- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I never knew that SE for Electronics also existed! I am updating the question and would also post one at electronics.SE! Thanks Ben Crowell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to acquire knowledge equivalent to that of people studying electrical engineering I'd find a person that does and then ask them for a list of course litterature. This should be a good place to start. For myself i can chime in with "Field and Wave Electromagnetics" by Cheng, any big book about university physics, "Microelectronic circuits and design", "Semiconductor physics and devices" - Neamen, "Calculus" - Robert A Adams, "Microwave Engineering" - Pozar. This is just a selection of the books which i found useful for myself. Then of course there were also a lot of books suggested/required for the teacher that did not help us at all.

A word of warning to you however is that be aware that at times it might be tough. There is a reason that this degree is generally 3-5 years full time depending on where you take it. For me it was 5 years (3 yr bachelor and 2yr master).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to find: https://www.edx.org/learn/electrical-engineering . Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ocean but EdX isn't complete in its own courses! And the things are much kinda low too. Not every resource is available, it would be great if there was a curriculum type!